# PHP- putting database results in array and attach a variable

Tags: php, json

I'm pulling records from a database which i'm able to display the data in JSON format the way i want and it works perfectly. The problem here its there's a token i generate on the page which i want to add to the payload that the user gets and this's what i'm getting

```
{"user_details":[{
                "id":"1",
                "fname":"xxx",
                "lname":"xxx Mensah",
                "phone_number":"0000000",
                "email":"yourmail@mail.com",
                "username":"xx",
                "password":"xx",
                "user_type":"xx"
                }],
"token":"xxxxx"}
```

but i want to get the results like this

```
[{"user_details":{
                "id":"1",
                "fname":"xxx",
                "lname":"xxx Mensah",
                "phone_number":"0000000",
                "email":"yourmail@mail.com",
                "username":"xx",
                "password":"xx",
                "user_type":"xx"
               },
"token":{"xxxxx"}
]
```

PHP

```
$token = xxxxx
$row = $conn->query("SELECT * from users where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userdetails = $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$results = array(
    'user_details' => $userdetails,
    'token' => $token
);
echo json_encode(($results));
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Your required JSON is not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

It seems that expected json is not valid (the token part), but you can have something similar that looks like this :

```
[{"user_details":{"id":"1","fname":"xxx","lname":"xxx Mensah","phone_number":"0000000","email":"yourmail@mail.com","username":"xx","password":"xx","user_type":"xx"}},{"token":"xxxxx"}]
```

Code :

```
$token = xxxxx;

$row = $conn->query("SELECT * from users where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$userdetails = $row->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$results = array(
    array(
        'user_details' => $userdetails
    ), 
    array(
        'token' => $token
    )
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Notice that the result is wrapped inside another array and the token is inside another array.

The fetchAll is replaced by a fetch since you need only one row not all the rows, right ?

This example can help you to know how your data should be structured in order to get the desired result :

```
<?php

$array = array(
  array (
    'user_details' => 
      array (
        'id' => '1',
        'fname' => 'xxx',
        'lname' => 'xxx Mensah',
        'phone_number' => '0000000',
        'email' => 'yourmail@mail.com',
        'username' => 'xx',
        'password' => 'xx',
        'user_type' => 'xx',
      ),
  ),
  array(
      'token' => 'xxxxx'
  )
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: This is really close, so I'm upvoting.  Key is identification that code needs to do fetch() vs fetchall().

Answer (score 1):

The [] brackets in a JSON encoded string representation of an object, whilst the {} brackets represents an array. So your user details are showing an object which is an array of key, value pairs. Then you have an array which wraps everything up, the token and user details.

I'd be inclined to try something along the lines of:

```
$userdetails = $row->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$object = (object) ['userdetails' => $userdetails, 'token' => $token];
echo json_encode($results);
```

I haven't tested it out, but should be close enough.

Comment: It's the opposite of your statement.  [] is array, {} is an object.

Comment: I knew replying to questions so late at night was a mistake. :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  I figured as much given that your code reflects the basic issue.  With that said, the underlying problem is that he gets an array with an object in it, and that will serialize in the form he doesn't like regardless.

Comment: Add the fetch() change and I think your answer gets him closest to the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

did you make a typo?
please try this one :

```
echo json_encode ([$results]);
```